# pygame - How to make a circle move based on an event?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.3

I already have the event in mind; a button will be pressed which moves a circle to a coordinate that I assign it to, but how do I actually MOVE the counter? I've tried bliping it but that has not worked.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to have a certain variable in your program that changes when the player pushes the button.  When the variable has the original value, the circle should be drawn at the first location, and when the variable has the new value, the circle will be drawn at the new location.

Here is an example code:

```
import pygame, sys
x=False
oldLocation=(100, 100)
newLocation=(200, 200)
window=pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key==pygame.K_SPACE:
            x=True
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    if x:
        pygame.draw.circle(window, (0, 0, 0), newLocation, 50)
    else:
        pygame.draw.circle(window, (0, 0, 0), oldLocation, 50)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Would it be possible if you should be some sample code for that? I understand what you're saying but seeing it in action would be even cooler :D

Comment: Thanks so much. Selected it as the answer.